# Trying to use nested if statements inside forEach loop on javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to use an if statement inside of another if statement and I simply can't figure out how to get the second if statement to work. The second if statement applies all style changes to the first element (school) in the array. I would like the second if statement to apply the correct styling to all items in the array based on the json data ([school.status]).

I've tried switching to a for statement, tried moving the if statements around and nesting them differently, tried async and moving different parts of the formulas in and out of the code blocks. I've tried running a second forEach statement after the append but I couldn't get that to work either. I think I lack an understanding of how this process works, beyond just the code part, but more the logical operator, and after hours of searching for a straight forward answer, and it being almost 4AM, I figured I would just ask here.

```
schools.forEach(function(school, index) {
  dashboardItemStatus = $(".dashboard-item-status");
  if (App.hasClass("mainDash")) {
    App.append(
      '<div class="dashboard-item"><h5 class="mb-1">' +
        [school.name] +
        "</h5>" +
        '<p style="margin-bottom: -2px">' +
        [school.address.street] +
        "</p>" +
        '<p style="margin-bottom: -2px">' +
        [school.address.city] +
        "," +
        " " +
        [school.address.state] +
        " " +
        [school.address.zip] +
        "</p>" +
        '<p style="margin-bottom: -2px">' +
        [school.phone] +
        "</p>" +
        '<p style="margin-bottom: -2px">' +
        [school.principal] +
        "</p>" +
        '<p style="margin-top: 8px;background-color: #FFF;padding: 8px 14px;border-radius: 5px;" class="dashboard-item-status" id="dashboardItemStatus">' +
        [school.status] +
        "</p>" +
        "</div>"
    );
  }
  if (school.status == "Normal Operation") {
    dashboardItemStatus.addClass("dashboard-item-status-normal");
  } else if (school.status == "Full Change") {
    dashboardItemStatus.addClass("dashboard-item-status-change");
  }
});
```

So, I suppose the expected results are anytime one of the statuses is "Full Change" the dashboard-item-status-change class is applied, and the dashboard-item-status-normal class is applied to any status that has "Normal Operation". That data is an array that is coming from a json file. That part works just fine. The forEach function works fine and the information displays correctly on the screen. Now though, I need to be able to affect the elements that show the status individually based on the status itself. Right now, as stated above, no matter what status I attempt to affect, the channges all occur on the first element in the array, which I guess makes sense, but I have no idea how to fix it. If I console.log() the names and statuses of the schools inside the second if statement, they display correctly so I know I can find the right values, I just don't know how to affect them. Maybe map or something may work but I honestly don't know how to use that correctly. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: The very first command inside your `forEach` loop is `dashboardItemStatus = $(".dashboard-item-status");` This will select *all* existing `<p>`s with that class, *except* the one you actually want, the one you'll be adding next.

Comment: Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/4xLrbnat/

Comment: @ChrisG Thanks, that works perfectly! That was driving me nuts and I just gave up at about 4AM... Thanks for working out the json, I should have added it in there along with my css to make it easier to visualize and make the question better. I appreciate the help!